# Web Scraping products when the IDs are different

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm following along with a few videos on YT to learn a bit about Web Scraping. The one thing I can't find out is with `soup_findAll(#,{#,:#})`, how would I pull items when all of the IDs are different?

Currently, I'm pulling monitor info from `MicroCenter`, and when I inspect element, the ids are `pwrapper_0`, `pwrapper_1`, etc. but the class is `product_wrapper` for all of them. How would I pull all of the IDs in without having to pull every single one separately?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.microcenter.com/search/search_results.aspx?Ntk=all&sortby=match&N=4294966896+4294821085&myStore=true'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)

# stores content into variable
page_html = uClient.read()

# closes client
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

# grabs each product, hopefully

containers = page_soup.findAll('id', {'pwrapper_#': 'product_wrapper'})
print(len(containers))
```

**Note: I'm aware that pwrapper_# is there, it's just a # for purpose of this question.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can select all the product by using jsut product_wrapper class. and you can also use for loop to select each product here you can use two ways.
**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.microcenter.com/search/search_results.aspx?Ntk=all&sortby=match&N=4294966896+4294821085&myStore=true'

uClient = uReq(my_url)    
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()    

page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

containers = page_soup.findAll('li', {'class': 'product_wrapper'})
print(len(containers))

for product in containers :
    #your code here

     #or

#set how many product you want
productNumber = 16
for i in range(0,productNumber,1):
    containers = page_soup.findAll('li', {'id': 'product_wrapper'+i})
    #your code here
```

Comment: hi there good day dear Govinda - many thanks for providing us with an answer: i just r unned this code on a freshly installed ATOM on WIN 10 and got back the following:  ´File "C:\Users\Kasper\Documents\_mk_\_dev_\python\_examples_\_micrometer_com.py", line 21
    productNumber = 16
                ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block´ AT the moment i am musing what goes on here!? Love to hear from you again

Comment: one more time your most  welcome. it is second way to do your work from line 21. you can remove the code from line 21 or  if you are using this then you can remove first one code.you can run whatever way you like.